# The problem related with the map $L\colon \mathbb R^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb R^{2}$ given by $L(x,y)=(x,-y)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I came across the problem which says:

> The map $L\colon \mathbb R^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb R^{2}$ given by $L(x,y)= (x,-y)$ is
>   (a) differentiable everywhere in $\mathbb R^{2}$,
>   (b) differentiable only at $(0,0)$,
>   (c) $DL(0,0)=L$, 
>   (d) $DL(x,y)=L$ for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$.

I do not know how to approach the problem.Any kind of hints will be helpful. Thanks everyone in advance for your time .

Comment: In general an approach could be to treat each question in turn, and answer by yes or no. Hint: this ia a linear map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is (a), since $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=(1, 0)$, $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}=(0,-1)$ wich are continuous in all $\mathbb{R}^2.$

Another way is the follow, we can write $L(x, y)=(L_1(x,y), L_2(x,y))$, where $L_1(x,y)=x, L_2(x,y)=-y$, it's clear that $L_1, L_2$ are differentiabl scalar field, in fact $DL_1(x,y)=(1,0), DL_2(x,y)=(0,-1)$ therefore $L$ is differentiable and 
$$DL(x,y)=\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & -1
\end{matrix}\right). $$

Comment: thank you sir. But what about options (c) and (d)?  Since {(1,0),(0,1)} is the usual basis of R^{2},we see L(1,0)=(1,0),L(0,-1)=(0,-1).So the matrix representation of L with respect to the usual basis is given by \begin{pmatrix}
1 &0 \\ 
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix} which equals to DL(x,y).  so options (c) and (d) should be correct. Am i right,sir?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: For a map $f \colon \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ to be differentiable at $(x,y)$ you need to find a linear map $Df(x,y) \colon \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ such that 
$$ \frac{f(x+ h, y+k) - f(x,y) - Df(x,y)(h,k)}{\|(h,k)\|} \to 0, \qquad (h,k) \to 0 $$
Your $f = L$ is linear. Can you spot a map $Df(x,y)$ that makes the numerator "small"? Compute $L(x+h, y+k) - L(x,y)$ and try to identify something that is linear in $h$ and $k$.